# Prove that $A/B$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, finitely-generated, free-abelian-group

Let $A$ be a free abelian group of rank 2. Let $\{e_1,e_2\}$ be a basis of A. 
Let $\{a,b,c,d\}$ be integers, and $B = \langle \{ae_1+be_2,ce_1+de_2\} \rangle$ subgroup of A of rank two. 
Prove that $A/B$ is cyclic if and only if $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$. 
I tried to decide what B looks like. I concluded that it looks like $a \mathbb{Z} \times (d-bc/a)\mathbb{Z}$ by Gaussian Elimination of the matrix \begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{pmatrix}
Can I now finish with saying that $A/B$ is cylic if and only if $\gcd(a, d-bc/a) = 1$ and conclude the result? Can I even divide in $a$ at first? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Smith normal form should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on the comment of @TokenToucan. Since $A$ is free abelian of rank $2$ you know $A \cong \mathbb{Z}^2 = \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle$. Moreover $B$ is the sublattice generated by $(a, b)$ and $(c,d)$.

Notice that this sublattice is generated by the matrix
\begin{equation*}
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a & c\\
b & d
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

Recall that we may put this matrix in Smith normal form by replacing $M$ by $SMT$ where $S$ and $T$ are invertible. So we may assume
\begin{equation*}
M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha & 0\\
0 & \beta
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
I will leave it to you to check that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are coprime if and only if $gcd(a, b, c, d) = 1$.